# PowerMock NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I have some simple classes I'm using to see if I can get `powermock` to work:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooTest
{
    @Test
    public void testFoobar(){
        Foo test = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Foo.class, "foobar");
        PowerMock.replay(test);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Foo
{
    public String foobar(String aString){
        return aString + " blah";
    }
}
```

When I try to run this unit test, it tells me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/easymock/classextension/internal/ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor
...
```

I have no idea why its doing this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're including [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/index.html) in your class path when using PowerMock... you can find the download page [here](http://www.easymock.org/Downloads.html).

According to the [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/EasyMock) on PowerMock, it states that EasyMock is a dependency.

Comment: ... which means? Which PowerMock file did you download from [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/list)?

Comment: I have a custom third party build of powermock-easymock-1.3.8-full.jar

Comment: Did you read the description? It says it comes with the source but not the dependencies. You must manually download EasyMock and add it to the class path.